# How to create multiple pagination for multiple tables in same page with a single function using knockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js, paging

When I use single pagination function to display pagination for multiple tables in same page with KnockoutJS, then the last table does not render. I don't know much about KnockoutJS. But I want to simplify solution to reuse a pagination function and pagination template for each table in a same page.
Please Help, thanks.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/html" id="paginationTemplate">
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text:(holdTransactionFirstRecord() + 1)"></span> - <span data-bind="text:holdTransactionLastRecord"></span> of <span data-bind="text:holdTransactionsList().length"></span></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                            <a href="#" title="FirstPage" data-bind="click: holdTransactionFirstPage" target="_self">First</a>
                            <a href="#" title="Previous" data-bind="click: holdTransactionPreviousPage" target="_self">Previous</a>
                            Page <span data-bind="text:(holdTransactionCurrentPage() + 1)"></span>
                            <a href="#" title="Next" data-bind="click: holdTransactionNextPage" target="_self">Next</a>
                            <a href="#" title="LastPage" data-bind="click: holdTransactionLastPage" target="_self">Last</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
  </script>
    
  
  <table class="customtable" id="tblTeam">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th><span class="separator">Team Id</span></th>
     <th><span>Status</span></th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody data-bind="foreach:TeamPagination().holdTransactionPaginationData">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text:$data.teamId"></span></td>
     <td><span data-bind="text:$data.status"></span></td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
             </table>
    <div data-bind="template: { name : 'paginationTemplate', data: TeamPagination }">
      <table class="customtable" id="tblHoldTransactions">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th><span class="separator">Hold Date</span></th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody data-bind="foreach:Pagination().holdTransactionPaginationData">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text:$data.HoldStartDate"></span></td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
             </table>
    <div data-bind="template: { name : 'paginationTemplate', data: Pagination }">

<script>
  function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.ListOfStuff = ko.observableArray();    
    self.ListOfTeam = ko.observableArray();
    self.TeamPagination = ko.observable(new PaginationVM(self.ListOfTeam));

    self.Pagination = ko.observable(new PaginationVM(self.ListOfStuff));
    
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    self.ListOfStuff.push({HoldStartDate: "1/4/2020"});
    
    self.ListOfTeam.push({teamId:"1",status:"pending"});
    self.ListOfTeam.push({teamId:"2",status:"member"});
    self.ListOfTeam.push({teamId:"3",status:"member"});
  }
 
function PaginationVM(inputArrObj) {
 var self = this;
 self.holdTransactionPageSize = ko.observable(2);
 self.holdTransactionCurrentPage = ko.observable(0);
 self.holdTransactionsList = inputArrObj;
 self.holdTransactionPaginationData = ko.observable();
 self.holdTransactionFirstRecord = ko.observable();
 self.holdTransactionLastRecord = ko.observable();
 
 // The computed declaration for the number of display of records
 self.holdTransactionpage = ko.computed(function () {
 debugger;
  //Logic for displaying number of rows in the table
  var pgsize = parseInt(self.holdTransactionPageSize(), 10),
   fisrt = pgsize * self.holdTransactionCurrentPage(),
   last = fisrt + pgsize;
   if(last > self.holdTransactionsList().length)
   last = self.holdTransactionsList().length;

  self.holdTransactionPaginationData(this.holdTransactionsList.slice(fisrt, last));
  self.holdTransactionFirstRecord(fisrt);
  self.holdTransactionLastRecord(last);

 }, self);
 
 //The function for the total number of pages
 self.holdTransactionallpages = function () {
  var totpages = self.holdTransactionsList().length / self.holdTransactionPageSize() || 1;
  return Math.ceil(totpages);
 }

 //The function for Next Page
 self.holdTransactionNextPage = function () {
  if (self.holdTransactionCurrentPage() < self.holdTransactionallpages() - 1) {
   self.holdTransactionCurrentPage(self.holdTransactionCurrentPage() + 1);
  }
 }
 //The function for Previous Page
 self.holdTransactionPreviousPage = function () {
  if (self.holdTransactionCurrentPage() > 0) {
   self.holdTransactionCurrentPage(self.holdTransactionCurrentPage() - 1);
  }
 }
 
 self.holdTransactionFirstPage = function () {
  if(self.holdTransactionCurrentPage() > 0)
   self.holdTransactionCurrentPage(0);
 }
 
 self.holdTransactionLastPage = function () {
  if(self.accActivityCurrentPage() < self.holdTransactionallpages())
   self.accActivityCurrentPage(self.holdTransactionallpages() -1);
 }
}
  

  var model = new MainViewModel();
  
  ko.applyBindings(model);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag (`</div>`) is missing on the divs you bound with the template.

Add them like so:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name : 'paginationTemplate', data: TeamPagination }"></div>

<div data-bind="template: { name : 'paginationTemplate', data: Pagination }"></div>
```

Then it works like intended!